# clone or copy a python import

Tags: python, import, copy, clone

Say I have config file config.py with the following contents:

```
a = 1
```

Now in another file I do:

```
import config
x = config
x.a = 2
```

Now if you `print x.a` you will get `2`, but if you `print config.a` you will also get `2` because `x` and `config` is the same pointer.

Is there a way of somehow cloning or copying config to x so that I would have an independent instance x with the fields of config? I am aware of classes but I am trying to avoid them here. I have also tried using python's `copy` module, does not work here.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid classes?

Comment: its easier for end user to update config files, but I might have a go at python configparser if I can find a simple solution for this

Comment: You are not supposed to create instances of modules, this is what classes are for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Python's `copy` module is exactly what you need here. Change your code to look like this:

```
import copy
import config
x = copy.copy(config)
x.a = 2
config.a = 3
```

Now `x` and `config` will change independently of one another.

Comment: have you tried this. i am using python 2.7.something and it does not work.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'